# Conditional displaying of tab in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

In my `Menu` component, I have 2 tab like below

```
                    <span>
                        <Link to="inventory"> Inventory</Link>
                    </span>
                    <span >
                        <Link to="user"> Users</Link>
                    </span>
```

actually `Users` I want to display only for `users` who are `admin`. so whether user is `admin` or not I am checking in `Admin` component.

How can I bring data from `Admin` on `Menu` and display`User` tab conditionally?

I know I can wrtie something

```
{isActive && <Link>} etc
```

so in my `Admin` component I am calling `API` and bringing the `data`. and checking if particular valus is `admin` then I am making `isActive` as `true` and I need to send it to `Menu` component.

But I dont know how to bring `isActive` from `Admin` into `Menu`?
Could you please help?

Comment: Since we don't know what data you have, we don't know how to get isActive.

Comment: thank you I have edited the question. isActive existed on Admin. in admin I am calling API and based on data making isActive true or false.

Comment: Since the tags on your post mention redux, isn't isActive something that you could keep in your redux state?

Comment: actually I included redux for more visibility. redux I am not using.

Answer (score 1):

Generally to share a state between all components and refuse prop drilling the best way is use react context or in some cases use redux.
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html ==> react context